# Object of class SQLite3Result could not be converted to string

Tags: javascript, php, sqlite, xmlhttprequest

I'm trying to get a response from an SQLite DB, using an XHR on a PHP file, but I'm unsure how to handle the SQLite Object that's being returned  Currently, I'm just trying to console.log the response but I'm getting the error in the title.  Do I need to stringify the response perhaps?

```
<?php
$database = new SQLite3('cookieOrders.sqlite');

$statement = $database->prepare('SELECT creation_time FROM orders WHERE order_id = 1;');
$result = $statement->execute();

echo $result;

?>
```

-

```
function populateOrders() {
  var x = new XMLHttpRequest();
  x.onreadystatechange=function(){
  if (x.readyState==4 && x.status==200){
    var response = x.responseText;
    console.log(response);
    }
  }
  x.open("GET","./php/queryDB.php",true);
  x.send();
  return false;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to fetch data. Currently you are trying to `echo` a [`SQLite3Result`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/class.sqlite3result.php) object, which is the result of [`execute()`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/sqlite3stmt.execute.php) :

```
$result = $statement->execute() ;
$row = $result->fetchArray() ;
echo json_encode($row) ;
// or echo $row['creation_time'] ;
// or print_r($row) ;
```